# word or phrase to describe wanting to ask how someone is coping with something difficult but not asking due to respect?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, concept

Is there a word or phrase to describe the longing to know how someone is coping with something hard - illness, death etc - but not wanting to pry due to the painful nature of the person who is going through it, but the first inquisitive person wants the second struggling person to know he/she is there to support if needed wanted?

This seems like a hilarious question or concept as soon as I type it out but hopefully someone might have some ideas.

Comment: I think a lot of people would like to know a good word/phrase for that; I would. You should generally show some research with your questions here. Welcome to EL&U.

Comment: This seems like a component of being sympathetic or respectful, I'm not sure there's a more specific term.

Comment: For holding their tongue, they are *angels* (because only fools rush in).

Answer (score 1):

There is the multi word verb **hold back** (used with *from* + ing-clause) that often conveys the sense of restraining oneself from doing something that while on the one hand seems the right thing to do, on the other hand might well actually do more harm than good:

> *hold back* [phrasal verb of *hold*]
>
> 1. hesitate to act or speak.
>
> - *He held back, remembering the mistake he had made before*.

[[Oxford Languages Dictionary; courtesy of Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=hold+back+meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&oq=hold+back+me&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqBwgAEAAYgAQyBwgAEAAYgAQyBwgBEAAYgAQyBggCEEUYOTIHCAMQABiABDIHCAQQABiABDIHCAUQABiABDIHCAYQABiABDIHCAcQABiABDIHCAgQABiABDIHCAkQABiABKgCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)]

**Hesitate** [to do something} is an alternative, though it conveys less implication that the reluctance won't be overcome.

- *I hesitated to inquire how George was coping.*

Of course, both of these expressions have far wider application than merely to not blunder in with insensitive solicitations.